# Prove a match statement

Tags: pattern-matching, coq

Trying to solve an exercise, I have the following definition that represents the integers :

```coq
Inductive bin : Type :=
| Zero : bin
| Twice : bin -> bin
| TwiceOne : bin -> bin.
```

The idea is that :

1. Twice `x` is `2*x`.
2. TwiceOne `x` is `2*x +1`.

However, this representation has a problem: there are several representations of the number `0`.

Therefore, I need to implement a function that normalize a number writing in `bin`.

To do this I have declared the following function :

```coq
Fixpoint normalize_bin (b:bin) : bin :=
  match b with
    | Zero => Zero
    | TwiceOne x => TwiceOne (normalize_bin x)
    | Twice x => match normalize_bin x with
                   | Zero => Zero
                   | x => Twice x
                 end
  end.
```

And now, I want to show that if a take a `b` of type `bin`, I translate `b` in `nat` and then I come back to `bin` I get the b' that is the normalized of `b`. This is the following theorem :

```coq
Theorem bin_to_nat_to_bin : forall (b:bin),
                              nat_to_bin (bin_to_nat b) = normalize_bin2 b.
```

To prove this theorem I do an induction on `b`. But I am getting stuck in the indu

ctive case since I need to show that:

```coq
   nat_to_bin (bin_to_nat Tb + bin_to_nat Tb) =
   match normalize_bin2 Tb with
   | Zero => Zero
   | Twice b => Twice (Twice b)
   | TwiceOne b => Twice (TwiceOne b)
   end
```

After using the tactic `simpl`.

However, I have no idea how to deal with this match in the goal. What can I do from here ?

Since this exercise come from a book, I don't have to use some advanced things of Coq. I just know some tactics like `reflexivity`, `simpl`, `rewrite`, `destruct`, `assert`.

A second normalization possible is just to declare this :

```coq
Definition normalize_bin (b:bin) : bin :=
  nat_to_bin (bin_to_nat b).
```

But in this case it is trivial and I don't think that is the answer expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is an exercise from Software Foundations, I won't give the full answer, but a hint.

This proof is indeed quite tricky. When you get in the middle of a complicated proof like this, it's usually a good idea to try to factor it into smaller lemmas. This in turn might require reorganizing your definitions so that the statements of these lemmas become simpler.

In your case, your definition of `normalize_bin` has an inner `match` that looks a bit too complicated, which becomes apparent once you get into that point of your proof. Can you factor that inner `match` in a separate definition so that you can state lemmas about that definition and use those lemmas later in your main proof?

Comment: Indeed it is an exercice from Software Foundations and I don't know if it is right to give a piece of answer (due to my definition of normalize). However, thanks for this answer, I'll try to think about that. So, if another time I come up with a goal like this, I should factorize the definitions and use lemmas ? It is "always" possible ?

Comment: Well, that's why mechanized theorem proving is hard! When proofs get more and more complicated, there isn't really a way of completing them by brute-forcing them, and when somebody is able to finish them at all it's because they were able to organize their definitions to make proofs doable. As you gain more experience, you learn how to organize your developments more effectively so that your proofs work better.

Comment: I got it. I spend one hour on it but finally I got it. It's not very difficult just, indeed, using lemmas is very useful.

Comment: I was stuck at exactly the same point. The hint to pull out the inner match so you can prove lemmas about it was exactly what I needed, thanks!