# normalize (normalize n) = normalize (n)

Tags: coq

I am working thru the examples in Software Foundations. In the induction section one of the exercises involves creating a normalizing function and proving certain things about it.

I was able to figure out most of the parts, albeit there was a place that I got stuck on regarding the proof.

[Prove a match statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504453/prove-a-match-statement)

Presents this exercise I am referring to, and thru that post I was able to figure out how to solve the exercise.

The question now is, why do I get stuck in my proof if I don't decide to factor out the nested match in the normalize function declaration. The part that I get stuck is proving the idempotent-ness of normalize, or

```
normalize (normalize n) = normalize (n)
```

Why does taking out the nested match and re declaring it as a new function allow things to work?
(After proving an additional statement relating this new function and normalize that is).

Am I missing something fundamentally about how proofs work in Coq ? Or is there a way to complete this exercise with this declaration of normalize

```
Fixpoint normalize (n : bin): bin :=
match n with 
  |  Z => Z
  | B1b n' => B1b (normalize n')
  | B0b n' => match  (normalize(n')) with
              | Z => Z
              | n'' => B0b n'' 
              end
end.
```

as opposed to

```
Definition helper_norm (n:bin):bin :=
match  n with
  | Z => 
  | n'' => B0b n'' 
end.



Fixpoint normalize (n : bin): bin :=
match n with 
  |  Z => Z
  | B1b n' => B1b (normalize n')
  | B0b n' => helper_norm(normalize(n'))
end.
```

**EDIT**
For those going through the tutorials from software foundations. It may be useful to know how to simplify a hypothesis...... , as far as I know the chapters prior to this exercise do not mention how to do so. Otherwise to solve exercise will have to do the factoring out.....

Comment: At what point do you get stuck?

Comment: When I am proving normalize (normalize n) = normalize (n). I get stuck after applying induction to n. (When using the definition of normalize given in the first block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a need to do this here. You just need to `destruct` the right thing in the complicated case, and then everything falls out of there.

```
Inductive bin : Type :=
| Zero : bin
| B0b : bin -> bin
| B1b : bin -> bin.

Fixpoint normalize (n : bin) : bin :=
  match n with
  | Zero => Zero
  | B0b n =>
    match normalize n with
    | Zero => Zero
    | n => B0b n
    end
  | B1b n => B1b (normalize n)
  end.

Theorem normalize_idem (n : bin) : normalize (normalize n) = normalize n.
Proof.
  induction n as [ | n rec | n rec]; simpl.
  - admit.
  - destruct (normalize n) as [ | n' | n']; simpl in *; admit.
  - admit.
Qed.
```

I don't think it's possible for a definition to make anything possible that wasn't already possible. Any lemma whatsoever that you prove about `helper_norm x` is also true and just as provable for `match x with | Z => Z | n => B0b n end`, since these expressions are convertible. It might be *cleaner* or more understandable to separate the proof into parts (in this case, we'd pull some part of the `destruct (normalize n) ...` case out to a new lemma, where we can probably generalize `normalize n` to any `n : bin`), but I don't think you gain any power. Also, though the underlying proof language does not really distinguish definitions from their unfoldings, tactics directly interact with the syntax of expressions, so cleaner expressions mean that tactics are less likely to get confused (e.g. try `rewrite ... at ...`ing a dozen occurrences of a variable vs maybe just one when the offending term is stowed into a function). Maybe there's an example that I'm missing, but splitting definitions into smaller ones is not to make more proofs possible, but just to make it easier on our minds to understand what's going on.

Comment: Hello there, that's what I thought initially,  that there is some sort of inherent structure that isn't perhaps conveyed without factoring out, but like you said, they are convertible. Anyways, I tried your code, and I have a couple questions. Why the use of admit? Doesn't that not proof it really? When I try going thru the proof for normalize_idem I get the warning  " (in proof normalize_idem): Attempt to save a proof with given up goals. If this is really
what you want to do, use Admitted in place of Qed. "

Comment: @nd2 Yes, I intentionally left it incomplete, as otherwise I would be posting solutions to the textbook question. I have the complete proof, so I know it is possible, but you should try to complete it yourself instead of having me tell you.

Comment: Ahhh. Oh my goodness.... I got stuck previously because I couldn't simplify the hypothesis by just calling simpl. Did not know of what simpl in does before this. Now all is well. Gotta learn the tactics. Thanks for the clarification.